# jQuery variable is not updating on dynamic created textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-uploading

I am trying to detect the current button click to assign values to its respective textboxes. Each time I select any of the button, it will detect the first button click and assign the value to the first textbox. Meaning to say that, the second and third button values are assigned to the first textbox. The `upload_textbox` variable is not changing its value.

I did some error testing, when `upload_textbox` variable enters `custom_uploader.on('select', function()`, the value stays and will not change. I am not sure on why it doesn't.

What have I done wrong here? Below are my codes:

```
function dynamic_image( button  ) 
{
    var custom_uploader;
    $(button).on('click','input.button',function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $clickedInput  = $(this);// JQuery Object of section2_2
        var clickedInputId = $clickedInput.attr('id'); // section2_2
        var upload_textbox = '#' + 'upload_image_' + clickedInputId;

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media(
        {
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() 
        {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $(upload_textbox).val(attachment.url);
            //console.log(upload_textbox);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();
    })
}

dynamic_image('#TextBoxesGroup');
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row">
        <label for="component1"> Component 1</label>
        <br></br>
        <input type='button'  class="button button-large" value='+' id='addButton'>
        <input type='button'  class="button button-large" value='-' id='removeButton'>
        <input type='button'  class="button button-large" value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
    </th>

     <td>
         <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
             <div id="ImageDiv1">
                 <input id="section2_1" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" name="upload_s2_1"/>
             </div>
             <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
                 <label>Title #1 : </label>
                 <input type='text' id='title1' />
             </div>
             <div id="DescDiv1">
                 <label>Description #1 : </label>
                 <input type='text' id='description1' /><br></br>
             </div>
         </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>5){
        alert("Only 5 components are allowed");
        return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    var newDescDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'DescDiv' + counter);
    var newImageDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'ImageDiv' + counter);
    var newUploadDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'UploadDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Title #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="title_section2_' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newDescDiv.after().html('<label>Description #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="descbox' + counter + 
      '" id="desc_section2_' + counter + '" value="" ><br></br>');

    newImageDiv.after().html('<input class="button" type="button" name="upload_s2_' + counter + 
      '" value="Upload Image" id="section2_' + counter + '"  >');

    newUploadDiv.after().html('<input type="text" name="image_url_' + counter + 
      '" id="upload_image_section2_' + counter + '"  >');


    newUploadDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    newImageDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    newDescDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");




    counter++;
 });

 $("#removeButton").click(function () {
      if(counter==1){
          alert("No more component to remove");
          return false;
      }   

       counter--;

       $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
       $("#DescDiv" + counter).remove();
       $("#ImageDiv" + counter).remove();

    });

    $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
            msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
        }
        alert(msg);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you make it as a fiddle and share the url??

Comment: Well, can you provide related HTML?

Comment: @Regent, I have added the related HTML and also with the jQuery script

Comment: Try to add `var upload_textbox;` after `var custom_uploader;` (before `button` click handler) and to replace `var upload_textbox = '#' ...` with `upload_textbox = '#' ...`

Comment: @Regent, I'll check it once I reached home. Seems promising. Thanks

Comment: @Regent , sorry for the late reply. I have tested it, it is still not working. I removed the return; statement from the if(custom_uploader){} function. It is not working. But the custom_uploader will always open twice this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question. The culprit behind this was the custom_uploader mentioned by @Aman. There was a return statement there where it made the function not to take the new value that has been replaced. After doing so, the custom_uploader opens twice because there is two statement of it which it was called. Did it into an if else statement and had it the way I wanted. Below is my updated code.

```
function dynamic_image( button  ) 
{
    var custom_uploader;
    var upload_textbox;
    $(button).on('click','input.button',function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $clickedInput  = $(this);
        var clickedInputId = $clickedInput.attr('id');
        upload_textbox = '#' + 'upload_image_' + clickedInputId;


        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media(
        {
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() 
        {

            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $(upload_textbox).val(attachment.url);

        });

        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
        }else
            //Open the uploader dialog
            custom_uploader.open();

    })
}
```

@Aman, you have mentioned about optimizing it. It seems quite fast at the moment. Maybe if there is a way to optimize it for the better, it would be a great help.

Thank you all, @Regent, @Aman, @Bhushan Kawadkar, @Arindam Nayak, @Raj

Answer (score 1):

Then I suspect this could be the culprit.

```
//If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }
```

This would always give you instance of first custom_uploader object. 
Try to destroy the previous instance and generate new one.

Comment: For all that I understood, the whole idea is to not destroy `custom_uploader` instance. Without related HTML and full example fiddle it is just guessing, and as I have already said, it doesn't look like correct one.

Comment: This might not be correct one but can give exact location of crack in the code. Once confirmed, we can discuss about optimizations.

Comment: From what I've known through the code, regarding your answer, that condition checking statement is to allow it to call the object again and again. Or else it will only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue with the event binding within **dynamic_image** method.

Try

```
$(button).live('click',function(e) (deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 though)
```

or

```
$( document ).on( 'click', button, data, function(e)
```

instead of

```
$(button).on('click','input.button',function(e)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: `.live` is deprecated and `.on()` is right way to bind event

Comment: I have tried, yeah it is not working. I did some error testing, when upload_textbox enters custom_uploader.on('select', function() , the value stays and will not change.

Comment: Yes @Regent , but i did tried Aman's new edited post on $( document ).on( 'click', button, data, function(e) , it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following.

```
$(button).change(function(){
//Write code  here
});
```

Comment: Why do you think it will help? `#TextBoxesGroup` is not `input`.

Comment: from the given code it seems button input is actually a textbox, so there if we input some text, it will definitely fire up change event, that is why , i suggested this.